# Lists are reversed when their new contents are not declared within the loop that's filling them. Why?

Tags: c#, list, reverse, arcgis

This is a "why" question, not a "how" question. I am coding a little ArcGIS project in C#, and I had to build two lists to do some later stuff. Here's the code:

```
List<double[]> store_coords = new List<double[]>();
List<IPoint> store_points = new List<IPoint>();

double[] templist = new double[2];
IPoint newpoint = new PointClass();

IFeature feature = null;
while ((feature = buildingCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
{
    IPolygon gon = (IPolygon)feature.Shape;

    templist[0] = gon.FromPoint.X;
    templist[1] = gon.FromPoint.Y;
    store_coords.Add(templist);

    newpoint.X = gon.FromPoint.X;
    newpoint.Y = gon.FromPoint.Y;
    store_points.Add(newpoint);
}
```

Now, after this, the store_coords and store_points Lists are entirely backwards. It's as if the Add method is putting templist and newpoint at the beginnings of the Lists instead of the ends.

However, when I add

```
templist = new double[2];
```

and

```
newpoint = new PointClass();
```

to the beginning of the while loop, the Lists are no longer reversed.

What is going on here? o_O

Comment: You shouldn't see the data reversed, you should see all of the items being equal, since there is only one array and only one point that's being added again and again.  When you move the declaration into the loop it means you're actually creating more than one type, rather than mutating the same one type over and over again.

Comment: Can you repro this without arcgis involved?

Comment: Is there any other code that modifies templist or newpoint later after the loop?

Comment: I don't know why people keep saying stuff about the items being equal. They are not equal; that's how I knew the Lists were reversed. Yes, the code was mutating the same object--but why does doing this reverse the Lists?

No code modifies the templist or newpoint after the loop. I originally intended not to use up more memory than was needed. This behavior sprouted from college professors.

Remember, this is a "why" question; I already know the "how to fix it."

Comment: I cannot reproduce this without using an ArcGIS object. Whenever I try, the resulting List is the same element in each one. This is where the "same items" idea came from. It's a basic pointer problem: each part of the List points to the same object. (I'm sorry I didn't realize this before.) But this does not seem to happen with ArcGIS objects. It seems to me that ArcGIS handles its objects differently. But how could object handling reverse the List?

Comment: The answer to your last question is simple: it can't. The behavior you describe is not possible given the code that you've shown.

Comment: But that's what happens with that exact code shown.

Comment: Are you checking the whole list?  My guess is that you're filling `store_points` with multiple references to the same point - so the last one in that list looks like the first one in the other list, but then so do all of them.  You may only need to move the `new PointClass()` line into the loop, so it's always creating a new point, and you're not changing the points you already put into the list.  If `PointClass` is indeed a class instead of a struct, it's being passed by reference, not by value, so you're just modifying the same point over and over instead of making new points.

Comment: Yes, I checked the whole list. It's entirely backwards; there is no duplication of any kind. Yes, I'm modifying the same referenced point--but I don't see how this reverses the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the code is doing:

```
List<double[]> store_coords = new List<double[]>();
List<IPoint> store_points = new List<IPoint>();

//Allocates a new double[] object in memory say TM1
double[] templist = new double[2];

//Allocates a new PointClass object in memory say PM1
IPoint newpoint = new PointClass();

IFeature feature = null;

//first loop
feature = buildingCursor.NextFeature())
IPolygon gon = (IPolygon)feature.Shape;

//double is a value type so the X and Y are being copied into T[1] and T[2]
templist[0] = gon.FromPoint.X;
templist[1] = gon.FromPoint.Y;


//adds a reference to Temp list to the list (a reference to memory location TM1)
store_coords.Add(templist);

//double is a value type so the X and Y are being copied into newpoint.X and newpoint.Y
newpoint.X = gon.FromPoint.X;
newpoint.Y = gon.FromPoint.Y;

//adds a reference to NewPoint object to the list (a reference to memory location TM2)
store_points.Add(newpoint);

//second loop
feature = buildingCursor.NextFeature()) != null

IPolygon gon = (IPolygon)feature.Shape;

//double is a value type so the X and Y are being copied into T[1] and T[2]
//this is updating double[] referenced by templist at TM1, so it is updating the
//array at TM1 that is being referenced by the List store_coords
//if you look at store_coords after these two calls you will see store_coords will have the new values already
templist[0] = gon.FromPoint.X;
templist[1] = gon.FromPoint.Y;


//adds a reference to Temp list to the list (a reference to memory location TM1)
//this should be adding the same object to the list so the list will have two references to
//the array stored at memory location TM1
// at this point store_coords not only has two cords with the same value it has two arrays
// that have the same value and are the same object in memory, so store_coords[0] == store_coords[1]
store_coords.Add(templist);
```

...

Comment: That wouldn't result in the lists being reversed, it would result in them all being the same items.

Comment: @Servy I agree with you.  They will be the same. Most likely Fenix is seeing the same elements, but this is what is wrong with the code.

Comment: All the elements are different; that's how I knew the lists were reversed in the first place.

Comment: The fact that what he's seeing isn't consistent with your explanation means that it's possible there is some other problem going on here, possibly in addition to this, and thus an answer is premature.

Comment: As I just learned (see my comment above), ArcGIS seems to treat its objects differently. The Lists are not composed of the same data. I'm not even sure if it's the same object in the same memory location. ArcGIS may create a new instance of its objects each time one is edited (I wouldn't put it past them to do such a memory-consuming thing). But the List reversal is what baffles me. What you're saying, though, is true for other objects (like lists and arrays). ArcGIS is different.